# How to save object to database using custom spring boot QUERY

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, model, mapper, nativequery

I am trying to save userdetails into database but when trying to save it i am getting error but fetching data their is no error.
I can't understand exact issue related with it.

My User Model is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

And my mapper is:

```
    @Query(value = "INSERT IGNORE INTO User (userName, active, password)  "
            + " VALUE (#{userName}, #{active}, #{password})", nativeQuery = true)
    <S> S save(User User);
```

what is correct way to save User in database?

Comment: Why do you use JPA and want to execute a insert statement?

Comment: Another point is Insert is not supported the way you want to use it: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_hql_syntax_for_insert